# IE 6 JSON response handling in blueimp jquery file uploader

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, internet-explorer, blueimp

I have implemented `blueimp jquery file uploader` and is running fine on all browsers except IE6 :(.
It is not handling JSON response from the `uploads_controller#create` method. It gives JSON file with response for download.

Please help me to sort this issue..

Comment: How are you returning your json? What `Content-Type` headers are you sending when you return the json to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it following way resoles the issue

`content_type = request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT'].split(',').include?("application/json") ? "application/json" : "text/html"`

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json{render :json => [ @attached_file.to_jq_upload ].to_json, :content_type => content_type}
  end`
```

Comment: what should we modify in our index controller ?? I have a problem in there :/